# c# windows forms application leaves process running after errors

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I'm writing my first c# windows forms app, and I'm new programming (I've done excel macros and years ago I used to write embedded stuff but I'm only a helpdesk drone trying to do something to help with my foreign-language study) and I'm essentially flailing about with no idea what I'm doing and googling a lot, which usually works, but I've been stuck on this all day.

My app accesses a database, and so long as it's up, everything's fine. I have try/catch/finally for the database access, and when there's an error, it's displaying the details, then closing the application - except it's still there as a background process in Task Manager and I can't figure out what it's failing to kill.

The main.cs has

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        StartupScreen MainScreen = new StartupScreen();
        MainScreen.Show();

        Application.Run();
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

and the catch for the error is

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error 7");
            if (conn2 != null)
            {
                conn2.Close();
            }
            this.Close();
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

If there's no errors, it exits cleanly when the user clicks the exit button or the X, but having to quit it with task manager if the database is having a hissy-fit isn't ideal. I haven't intentionally started any background processes, and Visual Studio put STAThread on the main.cs, which I'm guessing means that it's a single-thread app, but I only started trying to do this a couple of weeks ago, and my poor little humanities-student brain cannot cope.

Is try/catch the wrong way to do this in a WinForm? The beginners guide I started from was about console apps, and that's how it said to do it there, but my base assumption with all of this is that I'm missing something obvious to anyone competent...

Comment: Where is the `try` ? You did not who it ?

Comment: I didn't include the 'try', as I didn't want the post to be excessively long. It's trying to connect to the database - which is offline to see what happens when the app can't connect to it - to get a count of items, and it closes the connection in the 'finally'.

Comment: Hello @quantdev - see below for the particular brand of stupid I was guilty of here. I'm still getting my head around c# and OO in general. As I've tried to explain to my boss before, any muppet can write code - but it takes experience to write *good* code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Main` is a little odd. The standard one is more like:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new StartupScreen());
    }
```

You don't need to call `Application.Exit()`, either in `Main` or in your `catch`.

In the `catch`, calling `this.Close()` will close the form, causing your `Application.Run` to complete, and that's the end of your `Main`, so the app will exit.

Also, are you running your program from Visual Studio? If the process in the task manager is called `yourapplication.vshost.exe`, then don't worry about it - it's used by Visual Studio to help with debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Blorgbeard. I was getting desperate when I stuck the 'Application.Exit()' in there. I originally had 'Application.Run(new StartupScreen())' and clicking a button on there launched the second form (which controls the bit that does the database access, I wanted to have several different things the user can do) as a modal, but on error I was either getting the messagebox back repeatedly or a flickering copy of the StartupScreen form and it never actually closed... and I'd made the 2nd form a modal because closing the first one killed the app and didn't show the 2nd form.

Comment: ...presumably I solved the wrong problem there, but that's what my googling indicated I should be doing, I was trying to avoid having to post here!

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on in that case.. Can you try to reduce (a copy of) your project to a minimal example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Thanks @Blorgbeard, I did have a quick go, and I think I may know what the issue is now (because that one didn't do the same thing!) I'll try again in the morning and let you know.

Comment: Thanks again, @Blorgbeard. Producing the simplified version made it clear what I'd done - my initialization of the form wasn't calling the method `checkGameSize` where that try-catch was, it was calling `setupGame` which called `checkGameSize` and even when that failed it tried to complete the rest of the `setupGame`. I knew I'd be doing something stupid like that. A badly-structured mess is probably inevitable when the first go at OO code is attempting to replace 13000 lines of VBA with a lot of gosubs and gotos, so a useful lesson there.